# vuejs if/else: check if element exsists else add a element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `v-for` like so:

```
            <p> User Responses(s):</p>
        <template v-for="item in UserResponses">
          <ol v-if="item.some_condition==item._is_true">
            <li :name="item.id + '__UR'"> [[ item.some_variable_to_render ] ]] </li>
          </ol>
      </template>
```

Works great. However, what I would like to do is say `No user responses` when the `some_condition_is_true` fails, but if I add an `v-else` the message (No user responses) will be printed in every loop, which is not desired ofcourse. How does one solve this problem?

To this end, I wondered if I could test if the element `item.id + '__UR'" is present and if not add an element with text saying`No user responses`

I am not sure however that this is the correct way to go about this.

*EDIT*

Just to reiterate: using `v-if` before `v-for` is not an option since the object being iterated on is a nesed JSON which then is filtered through some vuejs filters, so yea, this is not an option.

Comment: Use `v-if` in the same `<template>` element along your `v-for`?

Comment: @kerbholz: that is not the recommended way to do it according to docs. I am not even sure how that would work. Can you show some code please?

Comment: why dont you use a v-else?

Comment: If there are no user responses, there should be no rendered templates. Can you simply have a second template with `v-if="UserResponses.length"`?

Comment: Right, missed that, sorry. On that same [guide page](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-v-if) there's an example of how to do it right though: Place your `v-if` outside of your `v-for` loop

Comment: @kerbholz: hmm I cant really do that `length` trick because the length is always `full` irrespective. So what I mean is I cant get away with running `v-for` first.

Comment: @WillAlexander: Cant do that.. I iterate through nested JSONs, so this is not an option.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

note that `boolVar` corresponds to your actual object key that contains the bools

```js
let model.flag = true

function foo(val) => {
  model.flag = val
  return val
}

<p> User Responses(s):</p>
<template>
  <div v-if="model.flag">
    <div v-for="item in UserResponses"   >
      <ol v-if="foo(item.Boolvar)" >
        <li :name="item.id + '__UR'"> [[ item.some_variable_to_render ] ]] </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1 v-else>No user responses </h1>
</template>
```

Comment: Hmm.. I cant do this because the `v-if` depends on the `item` being irterated on - I have now made this clear by editing the post.

Comment: so you say there can be items in the list but the items are kinda null?

Comment: Hmm.. well. wouldnt `h1` appear in every loop? Isnt that the problem with this approach?

Comment: that is why you have an else statement right? if true do this else do that. So no not both things happen

Comment: I added a third version that keeps the list intact

Comment: No, this is not correct. I would like `No user responses` only ONCE(when all the items have been iterated on and nothing has been found) - not everytime the item the iterated on. Your solutions will pick one or the other option for EVERY item in the loop.

Comment: so if a single item in the whole loop is false, you want no response? Or if all of them are false?

Comment: if all of them are FALSE - this is the whole problem :( So if all of them are FALSE, the HTML markup (<ol>) wont get excecuted.. and if this is the case.. Id like the `<h1>No user responses</h1>`

Comment: you can use `if UserResponses.map((item) => boolVar).contains(false)`

Comment: check my updated answer. It has this type of check there

Comment: Well, I have a filter which does some complex checking alongside it.. so, I would not want to touch this...

Comment: then please, go an rephrase your question. You keep declining answers which meet the initial requirement. Go and update your question with everything you actually want. Dot let us play the guess game.

Comment: on top of that, this map will take you a fraction of a second and you have what you want. You can always use your other map anyways. If it's not 10 million items, performance should not be an issue.

Comment: The question is clear - You are insistent that I change my loop. and I have repetedly told you this is not an option (this is why I asbtracted out the complex if logic). You seem to suggest again that I change my if logic - I do not want to do that (it isnt even my code). I also suggest in my question that a possible approach could be to watch for an element and if it does not exsist, inject `No user responses` in the DOM. Nevermind, thanks for your help - when I solve it I will post an answer.

Comment: ok but think about it want you want is kind of mind-boggling. You want to start iterating, even start rendering, and then if you encounter a bad item. You want to unrender the list again and render something else instead. The last thing i can think if is invoking a function in the if condition passing the values if one of them is true. you set a boolean flag in your model variables. Then you can wrap everything in an outer if and only render is this flag hasn't been set.

Comment: check my last edit. Something along those lines will probably do the trick. Im not sure if a great idea though.

Comment: @Your last edit makes sense - and it looks like the correct way to do it. I will read more on how to execute it for my use case.

Comment: finally, XD If I can help somehow let me know. Good luck.

Comment: thank you again. I have posted a related question now here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59555783/reseting-vuejs-boolean-value-via-template I am unable to reset the flag for some reason!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible you may be able to implement this using CSS:

```
ol + .no-responses {
  display: none;
}
```

There's a full example below but the idea is simply to hide the message if it comes after an `<ol>`. Tweak the selector to reflect your real use case.

I have tried to keep the template in my example exactly the same as the original code, with the addition of the relevant message and a couple of buttons for demo purposes.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  
  data () {
    return {
      UserResponses: []
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    add () {
      this.UserResponses.push(
        { some_condition: 3, _is_true: 3, id: 3, some_variable_to_render: 'A' },
        { some_condition: 3, _is_true: 4, id: 4, some_variable_to_render: 'B' },
        { some_condition: 4, _is_true: 4, id: 5, some_variable_to_render: 'C' },
        { some_condition: 5, _is_true: 5, id: 6, some_variable_to_render: 'D' }
      )
    },
    
    clear () {
      this.UserResponses.splice(0)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
ol + .no-responses {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>User Responses(s):</p>
  <template v-for="item in UserResponses">
    <ol v-if="item.some_condition==item._is_true">
      <li :name="item.id + '__UR'"> [[ item.some_variable_to_render ]] </li>
    </ol>
  </template>
  <p class="no-responses">No user responses</p>
  <button @click="add">Add values</button>
  <button @click="clear">Clear values</button>
</div>
```