# reseting vuejs boolean value via template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

For some reason (dont ask me why), I am having to reset a variable in VueJS via a template. So, In vuejs, I have this:

```
const someApp = new Vue({
delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
el: '#some-app',
data: {
    flag: 0,
},
methods: {
    changeFlag(val) {
        if (val === 0){//dumb stuff
            this.flag=0;
        }
        else if (val ===1){
            this.flag=1;
        }
        return this.flag;
    },
    ...
```

In my template I have this:

```
        <div :data-flag="changeFlag(0)"></div>
        <p class="card-text"> User story(s):</p>
        <template v-for="item in UserStories">
          <ol v-if="(some_complex_logic_here_via_filters )">
            <li :name="post.id + '__UA'"  :data-flag="changeFlag(1)"> [[ item.something] ]] </li>
          </ol>
      </template>
        <p v-if="(flag === 0)">No user stories found.</p>
```

The idea is that by excecuting `changeFlag(0)` and `changeFlag(1)` I can control the `<p>` tag later. However, for some reason, the browser seems to hang when I execute this. When I remove the `for` loop, everything seems OK - the `<p>` tage with no user stiries renders correctly. The error seems to be when I reset using `changeFlag(1)`.

I am quite new to VueJS and I am wondering if there is some usage error in this...

Comment: Why don't you just change the value of `flag` without a `changeFlag()` method. It would seem to be easier...

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup: how do I do that without a method? Can you show me some code?

Comment: `someApp.flag = val`

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup: do I execute this inside some html tag?

Comment: also, why wouldnt the method approac work? its VERY weird.

Comment: Well why can't you just do `v-bind:someproperty="flag"`?

Comment: See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247411/how-to-add-dynamically-attribute-in-vuejs

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup: `:name` is shortcut for `bind`. Also, I do not want the value, but rather want to invoke a change..

Comment: the problem is that `changeFlag(0)` works but `changeFlag(1)` does not and this is perplexing to say the least (I am  a back end dev btw, new to vueJS)

Comment: It seems to be that it has something to do with it being inside the for loop..

Comment: The `changeFlag` method is setting a value in `data`, which will cause the component to render again. This is likely an infinite render loop. Why does the value need to be set during render?

Comment: @RossAllen: you are correct Id think because the page never fully seems to load - but I still dont understand why this is happening. So, what I want to do is set the `flag` value in data while is rendered, so that I can manupulate other DOM objects using this flag.. What is crazy is that when I do [[ changeFlag(0) ]] once, it is fine, but when I again do [changeFlag(1) ]] it seems to go into some infinite loop :(

Comment: @RossAllen based on what you say, I should change the value of something which is not `data`.. but I dont know how else I can refer to the value back :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed an infinite render loop and also bad way to do things in Vue. **Do not change reactive data from your template (render function)!!**

Read about [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties)

```js
computed: {
  filteredUserStories() {
    return this.UserStories.filter( ...some_complex_logic_here_via_filters... )
  }
}
```

```html
<div v-if="filteredUserStories.length > 0">  
  <p class="card-text"> User story(s):</p>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="item in filteredUserStories" :key="item.id">{{ item.something }}</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<p v-else>No user stories found.</p>
```

This is not only much cleaner way to do this in Vue, it's also more effective because `filteredUserStories` computed property value is cached by Vue and recomputed only when `UserStories` change or some of the filters change (assuming those filters and their parameters are reactive)